# How to get a size(resolution) of desktop alert with javascript?

Tags: javascript, electron, alert, desktop-application, screen-size

I have a web app and a desktop client for it. I can send a different alerts from web to my client and I can use different alert for this (small, medium, large). I need to verify that an actual resolution of desktop alert and an excepted are the same.
My desktop client is building with javascript and electron.
I tried to use a lot of different "most common" solutions: something like `innerHeight`, `innerWidht`, `screenHeight` and etc.

Comment: No way it can be done to my knowledge. You'd have to create your own Alert box using `browserWindow` - which would be quite resource and developer intensive.

Comment: @Slbox I think that it's possible. I can make different operations with it (alert's window), for example, I can make a response, click on different buttons, close it and etc. 
But idk how to get a resolution :)
And I hope to find here some ideas for this.

Comment: How are you triggering the action like a button click? I did a bit more investigating and still don't believe this is possible, but if you can share how you're triggering the buttons to fire then maybe I can find something I've overlooked.

Comment: @Slbox I have selectors for alert's window and for all elements in alert's window body. So I call it and use basic methods